# AttributeError: 'Turtle' object has no attribute 'colormode' But my code have

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
import random

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.colormode(255)

def random_color():
  r = random.randint(0,255)
  g = random.randint(0,255)
  b = random.randint(0,255)
  random_colour= (r,g,b)
  return random_color

direction = [0,90,270,180]
turtle.speed(0)
# Remove the `where` variable since it is not used.

# Add a colon (`:`)` after the `for` loop to indicate the beginning of the loop body.
for _ in range(200):
  turtle.color(random_color())
  turtle.forward(30)
  turtle.setheading(random.choice(direction))

# Move the `screen.exitonclick()` function to the end of the code snippet so that the screen does not close until the user clicks it.
screen = Screen()
screen.exitonclick()
```

I am trying to generate a random colour with random walk but this error is coming

Answer (score 3):

I disagree with both of the current "import turtle" two different ways answers.  The issue is that `colormode` is a *screen* (singleton) instance method, not a *turtle* instance method:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
from random import randint, choice

DIRECTIONS = [0, 90, 270, 180]

def random_color():
    r = randint(0, 255)
    g = randint(0, 255)
    b = randint(0, 255)
    random_color = r, g, b

    return random_color

screen = Screen()
screen.colormode(255)

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.speed('fastest')

for _ in range(200):
    turtle.color(random_color())
    turtle.forward(30)
    turtle.setheading(choice(DIRECTIONS))

screen.exitonclick()
```

You can access the beginner friendly global `colormode` function directly via importing turtle (which is why the other answers work), but why would you do so when you've chosen the object API by importing `Screen` and `Turtle` explicitly.

Some modes are turtle specific, e.g. `radians` and can be invoked on a turtle instance.  But others apply to the entire turtle environment, e.g. `colormode`, and need to be invoked on the screen instance.  It's not always clear which are which without checking the documentation.

Comment: Thank you sir i was really worried about this as I thought my PC had some problem lol.

Comment: You're right--I've updated my answer to be a bit clearer.

Answer (score 2):

`turtle = Turtle()` creates an instance of a turtle (a single turtle). This is different than the turtle module itself, which is usually imported as `import turtle`. `colormode` is a function on the `Screen()` singleton instance, which is aliased on the `turtle` module as a top-level function, not on the `Turtle()` instance.

You can access `colormode` on the `turtle` module itself or on `Screen`.

Also, `random_colour` is a typo. I'd avoid the extra variable and just `return r, g, b` directly.

I've also formatted your code with [Black](https://black.vercel.app/), which I suggest using for all of your code so that it's easy to read for other programmers.

```py
import random
from turtle import Screen, Turtle


turtle = Turtle()
screen = Screen()
screen.colormode(255)


def random_color():
    r = random.randint(0, 255)
    g = random.randint(0, 255)
    b = random.randint(0, 255)
    return r, g, b


direction = [0, 90, 270, 180]
turtle.speed(0)
# Remove the `where` variable since it is not used.

# Add a colon (`:`)` after the `for` loop to indicate the beginning of the loop body.
for _ in range(200):
    turtle.color(random_color())
    turtle.forward(30)
    turtle.setheading(random.choice(direction))

# Move the `screen.exitonclick()` function to the end of the code snippet so that the screen does not close until the user clicks it.
screen.exitonclick()
```

By the way, if your editor doesn't have autocomplete, you can use `dir()` to figure out which methods are available on an object:

```py
>>> import turtle
>>> "colormode" in dir(turtle)
True
>>> "colormode" in dir(Screen())
True
>>> "colormode" in dir(turtle.Turtle())
False
```